# Unresolved reference: setOnClickListener on Selector when using LiveData to pass value from one fragment to another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I am new to Android Development. So now I have created a Tabbed Activity. I wanted to pass data from FragmentOne to FragmentTwo using LiveData and followed the tutorial here: https://android.jlelse.eu/communicate-between-fragments-and-activity-using-livedata-631526d6357a.

Unfortunately, the **setOnClickListener** was showing **Unresolved reference: setOnClickListener**.

FragmentOne:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.view.forEach
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import com.demicode.ccdofieldkit.ui.main.PageViewModel
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_one.*
import java.nio.channels.Selector
import kotlin.properties.Delegates

class FragmentOne: Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {

    private lateinit var itemSelector: Selector
    private lateinit var  model: PageViewModel
    private var average by Delegates.notNull<Double>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        model = activity?.run {
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PageViewModel::class.java)
        } ?: throw  Exception ("Invalid activity")

        // setOnClickListener throws a Unresolved reference: setOnClickListener error
        itemSelector.setOnClickListener {
            model.myAverage.value = average.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

FragmentTwo

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import com.demicode.ccdofieldkit.ui.main.PageViewModel
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_two.*
import java.lang.Exception


class FragmentTwo : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {

    private lateinit var model: PageViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        model = activity?.run {
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PageViewModel::class.java)
        } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
        model.average.observe(this, Observer {
            myAverageEditText.text
        })
    }
}
```

PageViewModel:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.Transformations
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class PageViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _index = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    val text: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_index) {
        "Hello world from section: $it"
    }

    val myAverage= MutableLiveData<String>()
    fun myAverage (item: String) {
        myAverage.value = item
    }
```

Error:

```
Unresolved reference: setOnClickListener
```

If remove:

```
import java.nio.channels.Selector
```

Another error pops up:

```
Unresolved reference: Selector
```

Comment: `import java.nio.channels.Selector` that is not an Android View

Comment: if i remove import java.nio.channels.Selector then another error pops up: **Unresolved reference: Selector**. Could you please suggest an alternative?

Comment: probably `View` in place of `Selector` lol